# Oracle, XMLQUERY not working on higher oracle version

Tags: oracle, xquery, xmltype

There was a query:

```
SELECT  XMLQUERY
        (
          '
            declare namespace tns = "XXX";
            copy $res := $req
            modify rename node $res/getTestService as "tns:getTestService "
            return $res
          '
          PASSING xmltype('<getTestService><envelope><source_code>xyz</source_code></envelope></getTestService >') AS "req"
          RETURNING CONTENT
        )
FROM    dual;
```

which gave

```
<tns:getTestService xmlns:tns="XXX"><envelope><source_code>xyz</source_code></envelope></tns:getTestService>
```

and this works on Oracle 12.1.0.2.0.

On Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 - same query - error:
ORA-21500: internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]

1st question - What Da...?

2nd - is there a diffrent way to add namespace as attribute and also get

Comment: You probably need to open an issue with Oracle support

Comment: Try with this.  modify rename node $res/getTestService as QName("XXX", "tns:getTestService")

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz - same error:/

Comment: I notice there's a trailing space in "tns:getTestService " . Might be worth trying without that. Don't have access to 12.2.0.1.0 so can't check myself.